# Can't clear input within Vaadin-grid?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have used a method in the past to make `paper-input`s blank in the past, however my usual methods are not working when in conjunction with `Vaadin-grid`.

Am I missing something here?

**Vaadin-grid HTML**

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
    <template class="header">
        <div class="horizontal layout cell">
            <label for="keyFilter" class="keyText cell flex">Key</label>
            <vaadin-grid-filter class="cell" id="keyFilter" path="key" value="[[_filterKey]]">
                  <paper-input no-float-label class="keyFilter" id="keyFilter" slot="filter" placeholder="Filter search" value="{{_filterKey::input}}" focus-target on-input="clearAppear" >
                        <iron-icon suffix icon="clear" class="clearIcon" on-click="clearField" clear-item-id="keyFilter"></iron-icon>
                 </paper-input>
             </vaadin-grid-filter>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template class="cell">[[item.key]]</template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

I have attempted the following JS:

```
// Attempt 1 - gives "undefined" within the dev tools 
this.$.keyFilter.value = '';

// Attempt 2 - finds the correct element, but does not set the value to blank
document.getElementById('keyFilter').value = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element's shadow DOM, use the standard DOM `querySelector` method:

`this.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector)`

So, for your problem use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#keyFilter").value='';`

And you have done a simple mistake in the above code i.e. providing same `id` name for  `vaadin-grid-filter` and `paper-input` element. Make sure to change this before trying the above code.